# Does the passport.js support ajax?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, passport.js, passport-local

I want to make ajax login with the passport.js. I have the usual code for setting the passport.js:

```
//route
app.post('/api/auth/login', passport.authenticate('local-login', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/login'
}));

//config strategy
passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
}, loginUser));

var loginUser = function(req, email, password, done) {

    UserRepo.getOne({
        'local.email': email
    }).done(function(user) {

            if (!user || !user.validPassword(password)) {
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'user or password is incorrect'
                });
            }

            return done(null, user);

        },
        function(err) {
            return done(err);
        });
};
```

This is my `react` component:

```
var Login = React.createClass({
  //...
  handleSubmit: function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var email = this.state.email.trim();
        var password = this.state.password.trim();
        var data = {
            email: email,
            password: password
        };

        api.auth.login(data, function (result) {
            console.log(result);            
        });    
    },

    render: function () {
        return (
            <form className="login-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <section>
                    <label>email</label>
                    <input name="email" type="text" />

                    <label>password</label>
                    <input name="password" type="password"  />
                </section>
                <section>
                    <input type="submit" value="send"/>
                </section>
            </form>
        );
    }
  //...
})
```

But, it doesn't work, because redirects (`successRedirect` and `failureRedirect`) do their work. If I delete `failureRedirect` I get `401` status. I understand that my code for `passport` for server side rendering and page refresh, but I cannot find any documentation for ajax login.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a custom callback to return JSON data.

```
app.post('/api/auth/login', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-login', function(error, user, info) {
        if(error) {
            return res.status(500).json(error);
        }
        if(!user) {
            return res.status(401).json(info.message);
        }
        res.json(user);
    })(req, res, next);
});
```