# Passport.js not redirecting after authenticating user

Tags: node.js, redirect, passport.js

I've set up a passport local strategy from passport.js so that I can register and authenticate users for my app.

Up till now everything seems to be working fine - network requests go through fine and users are created and succesfully saved to the DB.

However, the redirects within the `passport.authenticate` don't seem to be working.

authRoutes.js:

```
const passport = require('passport');

module.exports = app => {
  app.post(
    '/register',
    passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
      successRedirect: '/',
      failureRedirect: '/'
    })
  );
};
```

passport.js:

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = mongoose.model('users');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log('serialize:', user.id);
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
  User.findById(id).then(user => {
    console.log('deserialize:', user);
    done(null, user);
  });
});

// Local signup strategy
passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy(
  {
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  (req, email, password, done) => {
    console.log('req:', req.body);

    User.findOne({ 'local.email': email }, (err, user) => {
      console.log('error:', err);
      console.log('user:', user);
      if (err) { return done(err); }

      if (user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'That email already exists' })
      } else {
        new User({
          'local.email': email,
          'local.password': password
        }).save(err => {
          if (err) { throw err };
        }).then(user => {
          console.log('new user:', user);
          return done(null, user)
        });
      }
    });

  }
));
```

Github repo: https://github.com/drhectapus/Voting-App

UPDATE:

I cleaned up this bit of code because it uses a mix of callbacks and promises:

```
new User({
  'local.email': email,
  'local.password': password
}).save(err => {
  if (err) { throw err };
}).then(user => {
  console.log('new user:', user);
  return done(null, user)
});
```

When I clean up the above code to this:

```
new User({
  'local.email': email,
  'local.password': password
}).save((err, user) => done(err, user));
```

It successfully saves the user to the DB with no errors, but still doesn't redirect properly.

However, when I cleaned up the above code to this:

```
new User({
  'local.email': email,
  'local.password': password
})
.then(user => done(null, user))
.catch(err => done(err));
```

I get the following console errors:

In browser console:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/register 500 (Internal Server Error)
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 500
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:77)
```

In terminal console:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value).then is not a function
[0]     at User.findOne (/Users/Joseph/workspace/voting-app/services/passport.js:40:10)
[0]     at model.Query.<anonymous> (/Users/Joseph/workspace/voting-app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3919:16)
[0]     at /Users/Joseph/workspace/voting-app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:273:21
[0]     at /Users/Joseph/workspace/voting-app/node_modules/kareem/index.js:131:16
[0]     at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
[0]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
[0] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[1] Proxy error: Could not proxy request /register from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000.
[1] See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNRESET).
[1] 
[1] [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /register from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000 (ECONNRESET) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably caused by this:

```
new User({
  'local.email': email,
  'local.password': password
}).save(err => {
  if (err) { throw err };
}).then(user => {
  console.log('new user:', user);
  return done(null, user)
});
```

Which uses a strange mix of callbacks and promises.

Either use this (using a callback):

```
new User({
  'local.email': email,
  'local.password': password
}).save((err, user) => done(err, user));
```

Or this (using promises):

```
new User({
  'local.email': email,
  'local.password': password
}).save()
  .then(user => done(null, user))
  .catch(err => done(err));
```

**EDIT**: your edit added this relevant piece of information: `XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad`, so you're using `XMLHttpRequest` ("AJAX") to call `/register`.

In that case, redirects are handled as part of the AJAX request flow (the response to the AJAX request will be the redirect), and it won't redirect the *page* on which the AJAX request occurs.

To implement changing the page, you need to handle that client-side. There are various questions with answers on SO that provide an idea on how that could be implemented:

- [*"How to use jquery/ajax data for passportjs"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26019995/how-to-use-jquery-ajax-data-for-passportjs)
- [*"Does the passport.js support ajax?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29607497/does-the-passport-js-support-ajax)

Comment: I did as you said and updated my original post with the outcomes I got. Seems like the first one still doesn't redirect properly, and the second one i get a bunch of console errors

Comment: @JosephLiu the errors were caused because I forgot to add `.save()`, see edit. I'll add some additional explanation on why the redirect _seems_ to not work properly.

Comment: That makes sense then. I'm using react/redux on the front-end. Does that mean i should use react-router-dom to add a `history.push('/')` when I call the action creator?

Comment: If you're using a client-side router already, it's probably best to instruct it to perform the "redirect". If you're not using such a router, it may be easier to just use `window.location = '/'` (or [`history.pushState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method)).